# How can I make this sidebar?(discord clone)

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm creating a discord clone and this problem occurred. The message-sidebar was separated from the top-header after I made a new container(server-sidebar)

Check my CSS code:

```
.server-sidebar {
    background-color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 300px;
}

.message-sidebar {
    background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.795);
    height: 920px;
    width: 253px;
    margin-top: 100;
    margin-left: 80px;
    display: inline-block
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
.firstSideBar{
  background-color:black;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:10;
  height:72px;
  width:100%;
}

.secondSideBar{
  background-color:blue;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}
```